# How to Handle two people with same name in Apple Photos?

Tags: macos, photos.app, contacts.app

I am sorting my photos in the Apple Photos app via Faces, and have two contacts with identical names. Is there any way to create two "faces" with identical names, or do I need to change one of their names?

Comment: I would put their last initial or full last name.

Comment: They have same first and last name.

Comment: then they are the same person.

Comment: I don't know how Photos lets you use middle initials, but did you try adding M.I. (granted they don't have the same M.I. - in which case, you can use M.I. for one, and not for another)? Just an idea, please ignore if that's not allowed by Photos.